# Broadcast message (ping) cross chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to figure out a way which allows my extension to send a ping to all extensions installed within the browser.

The idea is the following, I have 3 separated extensions. One behave as the middleware, and tries to send a broadcast message to all other exciting extensions on the browser. The two extensions contain an event listener on the background where they will reply back their Id's. Consequently, the middleware background would be able to establish a connection with these extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't broadcast a message this way, but there is a workaround.

You can request the [`"management"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) and obtain a list of all extensions installed, and message them one by one.

```
function broadcastExternal(message, callback) {
  // Get all installed extensions an apps
  chrome.management.getAll(function(extInfos) {
    // Cycle through them
    extInfos.forEach(function(extInfo) {
      // Use `connect` if needed
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extInfo.id, message, function(response) {
        var result = { id: extInfo.id, message: message };
        // Check for errors
        if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          result.error = chrome.runtime.lastError;
        } else {
          result.response = response;
        }
        // Report either a response or an error
        callback(result);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

If you don't want the elevated privilege that results in a permission warning, you'll have to maintain a list of all IDs you expect to be listening and iterate through it. You could potentially store that list somewhere on the web and query it from time to time instead of updating the extension.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the getAll() function returns only a set of extensions. However,  this set does not include my other extensions.

Comment: Yes the are installed, moreover, it does return the extension which invokes the getAll().

Comment: \*shrug\* `getAll` should return everything that is installed.

Comment: Indeed, I have read the chrome extension documentation. It says that it does return a list with all the installed extensions, yet this is not working in my case.